# Problems storing logs in google Colab

Tags: python, logging, google-colaboratory

I have a function to set a log file that seems to work correctly locally, but I am having some issues when using it on Google Colab. The thing is that, if I quit the execution manually, the log file does create as supposed to, but if the environment disconnects or the execution finishes abruptly, the log file is not created. Is there any way in which I can cause this file to create and update itself gradually in order to not loose all the information in case the Google Colab environment disconnects?

```
def setLogFile(id = None):
    log_file_path = log_folder_path + "/" + str(id) + '_'+ str(int(time.time())) +'.log'
    os.makedirs(log_folder_path, exist_ok=True)
    log_file = open(log_file_path, "w")
    
    print("\n\n \t\t Results of the execution will be available at: " + log_file_path + "\n\n")
    encoding = sys.stdout.encoding if sys.stdout.encoding else 'utf-8'
    sys.stdout = io.TextIOWrapper(log_file.buffer, encoding=encoding, errors='ignore')
    return log_file
```